# Mapping an oracle number type in Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have a column (`OCPR_TIMESTAMP`) in oracle of type `NUMBER(18)` and want to select this column using hibernate. 
I have the hibernate mapping file mapped as..

```
<property name="timestamp" column="OCPR_TIMESTAMP" type="java.lang.Double" />
```

and the timestamp property in my VO as a Double type. 
When I select a record, the timestamp is always returned as null.
An example of the data stored in this column is:

```
7.18575602814979E15
```

I have tried various different types in the hibernate mapping, any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: The data point you showed us should be within range of Java's `double` type.  Can you show us any relevant Java code?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies - the persistence method being used was not hibernate, this was a web service using jdbc template so column needed adding to query string. Thanks for your response anyway Tim.